# Unable to login to a website using powershell

Tags: powershell, testing, automation, internet-explorer-11, webautomation

I am trying to login to a site using the below code,

```
$IE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application

$Url = "https://example.com"

$IE.Navigate($Url)

$IE.Visible = $true

 while ($IE.busy) {
 start-sleep -milliseconds 1000 
 } 



$elements = $IE.Document.getElementById("userID")

Foreach($element in $elements)
    {
        $element.value = "user"
    } 


$elements = $IE.Document.getElementById("pswd")

Foreach($element in $elements)
    {
        $element.value = "password"
    } 


$elements = $IE.Document.getElementByName("configCombo")

Foreach($element in $elements)
    {
        $element.value = "config"
    }
```

But except navigating to the url, nothing else seems to happen.The values in the username,password and config fields are not being filled up by the code.Looked for such cases in stack overflow but couldn't find any. So posted this as a new question.

I have unchecked the the enable protected mode in IE.

Any ideas/solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am also not getting any errors while i run it.

Comment: First off the element isnt an array. Its a single element so no need for the Foreach. you should remove those

Comment: @ArcSet2 If i remove the foreach then i am getting the error "The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property 
exists and can be set."

Comment: That is because the object is empty not because its a array

Comment: I did a Get-Member on the object and it returned that it has 'value' property. The foreach loop was suggested in one of the technet articles. The reasoning given in the technet article was there maybe multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: is the login box inside a Iframe?

Comment: No, it is not in an Iframe tag, but the configuration field has something called 'aria-activedescendant' tag. But i am not sure what it is, and couldnt understand what it meant from google.